# Absolute positioned div with dynamic height

Tags: css

I have a site based on foundation 5 & angularjs with the following layout:

```
header
-left-nav
--content
footer
```

Currently the left nav is absolute positioned to the left with an initial height of 100% (top:0, bottom:0)

The content div changes in height as to what is being loaded into it (via ajax). I'm manually adjusting the height of the left-nav div when the content height changes, but I was wondering if there was a way with html/css that would enable me to get rid of this script.

I've tried using all the techniques i've found through googling, but none seem to work without the javascript.. I need the left nav to always been 100% of the page height as it has a dark background that stretches to the bottom of the page.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/vn2wdbpm/1/ - Sorry for the massive style sheet, couldn't figure out how to create a file and reference it, u can inspect the divs to see the applied styles.

Comment: updated the fiddle.  but not sure if it will scale at larger size,  try it, if not,  inspect element with chrome and find out which css the div is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Its working in this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vn2wdbpm/2/)

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vn2wdbpm/3/) has an "add content" button which will show you it working with dynamic data.

I just changed this ...

```
 .small-fixed-130-left.column {
        position:absolute;
        width:11.4285714286rem;
        top:0;
        left:0;
            bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: when content gets added to the main content div via ajax, I'm pretty sure that the height stays the same as it was originally

Comment: I tested it for you in fiddle, by dynamically adding content, it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vn2wdbpm/3/  see for yourself

Comment: @BenKilah Posted an updated fiddle showing it working

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I do appreciate it, while that works in your fiddle, it does really accomplish what I'm after, check the second last sentence of my original post, needs to be 100% page height, not the same height as the main content div, cheers

Comment: So you want it to go past the footer ? @BenKilah So to cover the entire height of <body> then ?

Comment: yep, i tried many ways but always needed to come back to figure out the body height and applying some js watching the main content div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77948/discussion-between-notorious-pet0-and-ben-kilah).

Comment: Many thanks for the time you spent helping me through this problem, I highly recommend you to anyone that needs help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could position: fixed; the left nav with a height: 100%;